# Change done in the ValueChangeListener is not reflecting elsewhere

Tags: java, file-upload, oracle-adf, valuechangelistener

**Abstract:**

There is an `input File` competent in `JSPX` page where the user can select a file to upload. The user will press a `Save` button to store file in the database.

**Work Flow:**

1. When the user select the file to upload the `valueChangeListener` will be called.
2. In the `valueChangeListener` I am storing the file into local variable of type `UplodedFile`. I am able to access all file property from this variable in the `valueChangeListener`; that is, I can access the file name, size,... form the local variable within the `valueChangeListener`.
3. When the user press the `Save` button a method to `commit` the changes is called.
4. In the `commit` method I am getting the file data from the local variable that hold the file data.

**The problem is:**

This local variable that should store the file data is always `NULL`. I have no idea why this variable does not contain the file data although I set its value in the `valueChangeListener`.

**Note:**

I tried to bind the `input File` competent to a local variable and again it gave me the same result `NULL` value.

I am using ADF Technology JDeveloper 11.1.2.3

Comment: No idea why the down vote. The question is clear, well formatted and have answered by expert like (Timo Hahn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to process the data inside the value change listener as it's only present during the request. The file data is removed after the request.